# Colour/Shading Density Bar Plot

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure

Is it possible to create a colour density bar plot. I would like a plot such that it is effectively a 1D  plot (but a 2 dimensional bar) where the colour (or shading) changes according to a value of y between 0 and 1. The x-axis is just time. As we move along the x-axis the y-value changes such that 0 < y < 1 and changes the colour of the bar, say from white at y=0 to black at y=1 and shades of grey in between?

A sample of my data is imported in the form:

`[dates,extdamp,htgvlv,occupied,redamp,supdamp,clgvlv] = importfile1('MassImportAHU7.csv')`

Each variable is a 318x1 double and each value is an element of [0,1].

I hope this makes some sense. It's a tricky thing to explain! Many thanks.

Comment: MMM i think i got it, but can you post something as an example? Something like : http://xkcd.com/1410/ ?

Comment: Yer. Something along these lines. Something equivlent to http://biology.unm.edu/mmfuller/WebDocs/images/EnqDensPlot_labeled.jpg but with longer side being the x-axis. Cheers

Comment: Then you dont want something as strange as that what you are describing. I guess you have several 1D data arrays, am I rigth?

Comment: I have several 1-D arrays I wish to plot against date/time (by against I mean I want them to change colour according to their values at time t).

Ultimately I wish to stack them, one above the other so I easily compare them.

As a side note they are valve positions, hence the [0,1] and I wish to see how each one effects the others over the course of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several 1D variables, lets say, saved in a variable `A`;

you want to create an image (or a mesh) with all your data.

So I would do

```
img=A(:,1);
for ii=2:size(A,2)
   img=horzcat(img,A(:,2))
end
imshow(img)
colormap gray
colorbar
```

**EDIT:**
As you dont have image processing toolbox, you can do it this other way

```
A=rand(100,50) % sample data I created

Z=A;
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:size(Z,2),1:size(Z,1));
surf(x,y,Z)
view(2)
axis tight
colormap gray
colorbar
```

Result:

[image]

Then, if you want to change the X and Y tic kLabels, check this interesting answer:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92565-how-do-i-control-axis-tick-labels-limits-and-axes-tick-locations

Comment: I have had a look at this and I don't full understand what is going on here.  `img=A(:,1);` is not an image so when I do `imshow` i get this message:

Undefined function 'imshow' for input arguments of
type 'double'.

Error in (line 26)
imshow(img)

Comment: @josh edit your original post and show me some code of how the variables are stored in your case. If you define each of your 1D data as a row in an image, then all of them concatenated should become an image. the code I posted works if A(:,1) has your firs 1D data, A(:,2) tour second 1D data, and so on

Comment: At the moment the data is in separate arrays. I shall edit my comment now to include some of it.

Comment: @josh Well, if you have them in separate arrays, put them in the same array!

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it said undefined function 'imshow' for input of type double again. I'll keep play with it though.

Comment: @josh oh, you may not have image processing toolbox, let me edit the question

Comment: @josh now you shoudl be able to reproduce my optput. You just need to create your own matrix A

Comment: Yes. That worked and it is very close to what I would like as a final result. A couple tweeks with my data and it will be there. Thank you very much for all that help!!

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way in which I was able to draw a similar style graph to the above. It has its merits (from my beginners point of view) in that it is easier to manipulate and make it do my own thing without knowing lots of other functions and code. It also allowed me to change the shading and colour of the graph to a non-predefined setting over multiple variables. Computationally, I'd imagine it to be slower but was certainly quite fun to play with. The code is below from some predefined variables scaled between `[0,1]` barring date5:

```
A = [clgvlv,redamp,extfanstat,htgvlv,occupied,supfanspd]; %between 0 and 1
a = {'clgvlv','redamp','extfanstat','htgvlv','occupied','supfanspd'};
A(isnan(A)) = 0; %removing NaN's
date5 = %your dates/x variables

h=10 %optional scaling factor
K1 = date5(1)
K2 = date5(end);
K3 = 1/24/4 %tick-increments
J = size(A,2); % =2

%colour indicator
for j=1:J
    if mod(j,3) == 1
        Acol(j,:) = [0,1,1];
    elseif mod(j,3) == 2
        Acol(j,:) = [1,1,0];
    else mod(j,3) == 0
        Acol(j,:) = [1,0,1];
    end
end

%drawing Rectanges/blocks
for j=1:J
    for k=1:size(date5,1)
       rectangle('Position', [K1+ K3*(k-1), h*(j-1), 1, h], 'FaceColor', [1-Acol(j,1)*A(k,j) 1-Acol(j,2)*A(k,j) 1-Acol(j,3)*A(k,j)], 'LineStyle', 'none' )
    end
end

for j=1:J
    text(date5(end)+(date5(end)-date5(1))*0.02,(j-0.5)*h, a(j))
end

set(gca,'XTick',[date5(1):(1/6):date5(end)], 'XLim',[735881.5 date5(end)]) %delete if not dates
datetick('x','ddd HH:MM' ,'keeplimits','keepticks');
xlabel 'Time/Date'
ylabel 'Variables'
```

Hopefully this is helpful or at least amusing for some users.